# Showing MKAnnotation callout when clustered

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation, ios11

I have a TableView that is used to show MapView annotation callouts when the cells are tapped.
In iOS 10 I can centre the MapView on an annotation then show it's callout using:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let location = locations[indexPath.item]
    mapView.setCenter(location.coordinate, animated: true)
    mapView.selectAnnotation(location, animated: true)
}
```

`locations` is an array of `MKAnnotation`s. I'm using `MKPinAnnotationView`s on iOS 10 and `MKMarkerAnnotationView`s on iOS 11.

iOS 11 automatically hides and shows MKMarkerAnnotationViews as you zoom the map.

[image]

This has the unfortunate side effect of preventing `.selectAnnotation()` from working reliably because the marker could still be hidden after centering the map.

I've seen the docs and understand why:

> If the specified annotation is not onscreen, and therefore does not
>   have an associated annotation view, this method has no effect.

Is there a way to disable annotation clustering/hiding?
Or some way to force the selected annotation to be visible?

Comment: This is not a solution, but maybe an idea for a workaround: try zooming the map to a more zoomed in state programmatically (you can probably play around with the zoom factor to get it so that the annotations are not overlapped) after you center the map.

Comment: Hi @aksh1t I considered this but I don't want to mess with the users chosen zoom level. Plus some of my annotations can be very close together so this may not actually work in some cases.

Comment: That makes sense. Here's another idea that I got when looking at some of the other mapview methods: try calling the [showAnnotations:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1452309-showannotations) method with your annotation, and then do the `selectAnnotation`. (I do not know if the showAnnotation method changes the zoom level or not; it likely does change the zoom level).

Comment: `showAnnotations` does effect zoom unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `displayPriority` of an `MKMarkerAnnotationView` to a rawValue of `1000` and the less interesting `MKMarkerAnnotationView`'s `displayPriority` to something lower. This will cause that marker annotation to take precedence over others.

In your case, you will like want to hold a reference to the annotation that you would like to select, remove that annotation from the map view and add it again. This will cause the map view to request a view for the annotation again and you can adjust the priority so that it is higher than the annotations around it. For example:

```
    func showAnnotation()
    {
        self.specialAnnotation = annotations.last
        self.mapView.removeAnnotation(self.specialAnnotation)
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.specialAnnotation)
        self.mapView.setCenter(self.specialAnnotation.coordinate, animated: true)
        self.mapView.selectAnnotation(self.specialAnnotation, animated: true)
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
    {
        let markerView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "Marker", for: annotation) as? MKMarkerAnnotationView
        let priority = (annotation as? Annotation) == self.specialAnnotation ? 1000 : 500
        markerView?.displayPriority = MKFeatureDisplayPriority(rawValue: priority)
        // optionally change the tint color for the selected annotation
        markerView?.markerTintColor = priority == 1000 ? .blue : .red
        return markerView
    }
```

Where `specialAnnotation` is an object that conforms to `MKAnnotation`.